# javascript beforeunload not modifying data

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

Script evaluates onbeforeunload, saves to local storage but here is my problem: it does not alter any arrays or objects nor does it allow any new variables.

This gets in the way when I have objects I need to modify before saving them to local storage.

It seems like a limitation of JavaScript (since alerts are not triggered as well).

Is there any way to get arround this?

```
var saved = { hello: "world" };
var anArray = ["default"];

saveData = function ()
{
    console.warn('Saving data...');

    saved['test'] = true;
    anArray.push('something');

    localStorage.setItem('test', 'somedata');

    console.debug(saved);
    console.debug(anArray);

    window.onbeforeunload = null;
    console.warn('Done saving...');

    return true;
}

proxySave = function ()
{
    setTimeout(saveData, 0);
    return;
}

window.onbeforeunload = proxySave;
```

Comment: Why the `setTimeout()`?  Your page may be unloaded BEFORE the `setTimeout()` fires so it will never fire.  `alert()` is not allowed in an unload handler because it's too easy to abuse.

Comment: Why are you using `setTimeout`? Its only purpose seems to be to guarantee that nothing is saved at all.

Comment: I searched for solutions and a similar problem was suggesting a setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

The `setTimeout` means the code doesn't run during the `onbeforeunload`, meaning **all bets are off**. If you want to do something during `onbeforeunload`, do it **during** `onbeforeunload`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = saveData;
```

(And remove the `return true` in `saveData`.)

Yes, there are limits on what you can do in `onbeforeunload`, but basic object manipulation isn't one of them.

Comment: Okay, this really makes sense to me. Thank you for clearing that up.